# Output from Perl CLI regex save into file

Tags: python, perl

I would like to print output into text file with Python code.

```
cat test-01.kismet.netxml | perl -ne 'while(m/(?<\client-mac\>)(.*)(?=\<\/client-mac\>)/g{print $&; print "\n"})'
```

The ouput is what I want:

```
FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([["cat", "test-01.kismet.netxml", "|", "perl", "-new", "'while(m/(?<\client-mac\>)(.*)(?=\<\/client-mac\>)/g{print $& > clients.txt; print "\n" > clients.txt})'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

But it does not work.

The problem will be in this part:

```
'while(m/(?<\client-mac\>)(.*)(?=\<\/client-mac\>)/g{print $& > clients.txt; print "\n" > clients.txt})'
```

Thanks for any help or any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an xml parser, your life will be so much easier:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_doc = ET.parse('test-01.kismet.netxml')

for client_mac_node in xml_doc.iter('client_mac'):
    print(client_mac_node.text)
```

Outputting to a file is not any harder:

```
clients_macs = [client_mac_node.text for client_mac_node in xml_doc.iter('client_mac')]

with open('clients.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(clients_macs))
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, you've tagged this as perl, and you've already got a python answer.

So here's how you'd do it with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml = XML::Twig -> parsefile ('test-01.kismet.netxml'); 
print $xml -> get_xpath('//client-mac', 0) -> text;
```

But if you're embedding it in python, whilst I appreciate the cruel irony of 'shelling out' to perl, really you should just stick with Python's parser.

The key point being that XML is contextual, but regular expressions are not. A parser is the tool you should be using.

Comment: Thanks for it! A lot!